# how best to organize assets in a rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, organization

As I continue to make progress on my app my stylesheets folder has quickly become overrun. I've read the rails guide on the asset pipeline, and scoured the internet for a reputable source and am still at a loss on the "rails way" to keep everything tidy.

Before I go and try and develop a system by myself I was hoping to get some suggestions from you guys.

**Is there a well known "best practice" when it comes to asset organization? If not, what has worked well for you?**

As of now my setup is this:

```
app/assets/stylesheets >
```

**application.css, application-RESPONSIVE.css**

*any code specific to the body, containers, navbar, footer*

**controller.scss, controller-RESPONSIVE**

*any code specific to that controller

```
lib/assets/stylesheets >
```

*reset.css*

in application.css i use

```
*= require reset
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
```

To get all the styles however **I've also been wondering if its better to set *self* before *tree* as a means of overriding the main styles if need be?**

Comment: I personally feel one should avoid including anything but directives in manifest files.  So `require_self` would not even be needed.  Otherwise, the manifest file is just a nice central place where you can identify all of the assets associated with your project.  IMO much better include after include in each of my PHP scripts...

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that. Do you know if there are any examples of directories that have good asset organization I could take a look at? As far as subdirectories go to people just invent their own style or is their a convention for separating certain styles from another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a well known "best practice" when it comes to asset organization?

## **Organization of assets:**

In Rails, pipeline assets can be placed inside an application in one of three locations: **app**/assets, **lib**/assets or **vendor**/assets.

1) **app**/assets is for assets that are owned by the application, such as custom images, JavaScript files or stylesheets.

2) **lib**/assets is for your own libraries' code that doesn't really fit into the scope of the application or those libraries which are shared across applications.

3) **vendor**/assets is for assets that are owned by outside entities,    such as code for JavaScript plugins and CSS frameworks.

> Is it better to set self before tree as a means of overriding the main styles if need be?

**application.css** is what is called a manifest file. Now, it wouldn't particularly make any difference by switching self with tree, but it would change it's position in the loading sequence. Consider this...

Once you’ve placed your assets in their logical locations, you can use manifest files to tell Rails (via the Sprockets gem) how to combine them to form single files. These manifest files contain directives - instructions that tell Sprockets which files to require in order to build a single CSS or JavaScript file.

### **Additional info:**

One other thing that Rails does, is generate stylesheets for you when you run the `rails generate` command in the terminal. On creation of a new controller, you'll see a stylesheet with the controller's name in your assets. It'll look something like app/assets/stylesheets/newcontroller.css.scss

Also, what steve klein said.

Hope this helps you out.

#### ***UPDATE:***

> I've tried looking for examples on github but all of the apps I have found have been too simple and havent shown any advanced organization for a large amount of files.

I encourage you to check out [Open Source Rails](http://www.opensourcerails.com/) website. I have looked at some projects there and they seem complex enough for you to be interested enough. Especially, look at the [Discourse app](https://github.com/discourse/discourse). Discourse was co-founded by Jeff Atwood, co-founder of Stack Overflow. That I suppose speaks for itself ;)

Comment: Thanks! I knew everything you said accept for the sprockets part, in gona look into that when I get home. Do you have any suggestions for logical locations for style sheet placement? None of the rails web apps I've made have been this big and I've just kept all stylesheets in the app/assets/stylesheets folder.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, well yes this is as far as the Rails way goes.

Comment: @thesowismine if you feel you have too many separate custom style sheets cluttering up your `/app/assets/stylesheets` folder, you can always organize sheets in subfolders and then include them in your manifest file with the `require_directory` directive.  I strongly recommend you read the [excellent Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) on the Asset Pipeline.

Comment: @stevelkein yea thats what I as thinking, I was just wondering if there was a common way of separating these styles into their given subfolders. For example, should all responsive code go in one, should all controllers go in another? I've tried looking for examples on github but all of the apps I have found have been too simple and havent shown any advanced organization for a large amount of files.

Comment: I just updated my post with a good source of rails projects for you to look at. I am sure you'll be interested. Enjoy!